# Get max values in PostgreSQL 8.0

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, date-range, amazon-redshift

I'm Using **Amazon Redshift**. I need to get the **MAX** Date in the column by Month wise. The Example is as below.

There are 5 tables:

```
vendor
vendor_pkg
vendor_pkg_category
vendor_load
vendor_load_status

vendor  V

vendor_id   vendor_name
-----------------------
1            L&T
2            Reuters
3            IBM
4            INfosys

vendor_pkg  VP

vendor_pkg_id  vendor_pkg_category_id   vendor_pkg_name  vendor_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
1              1                        Futures          1
2              1                        Fairvalue        1
3              3                        Equities         1
4              2                        MBS              1
5              2                        INTL Price       2
6              4                        Muni             2

vendor_pkg_category  VPC

vendor_pkg_category_id  category_name
-------------------------------------
1                       Price
2                       Security
3                       Rating
4                       value

Vendor_load  VL

vendor_load_id  eval_date   load_status_id  vendor_pkg_id
---------------------------------------------------------
1               2014-06-05  1               1
2               2014-06-20  1               1
3               2014-07-05  2               2
4               2014-07-20  1               2
5               2014-06-05  2               3
6               2014-06-20  2               3
7               2014-07-05  1               4
8               2014-07-20  2               4

vendor_load_status  VLS

load_status_id  load_status_name
--------------------------------
1               Success
2               Failed
```

Result table should be like this:

```
v.vendor  vpc.category_name  vp.ven_pkg_name  vl.eval_date  vls.status_name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
L&T       Price              futures          2014-06-20    Success
L&T       Price              fairvalue        2014-07-20    Success
L&T       Security           MBS              2014-07-20    Failed
L&T       Rating             Equities         2014-06-20    Failed
```

I use the following query. But it displays the data for one month only:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.vendor_name AS vendor,
       vpc.category_name AS V_Type,
       vp.vendor_pkg_name AS Package_name,
       vl.eval_date AS C_Date,
       vls.load_status_name AS Status
FROM ces_idw.vendor v,
     ces_idw.vendor_pkg_category vpc,
     ces_idw.vendor_load vl,
     ces_idw.vendor_pkg vp,
     ces_idw.vendor_load_status vls
WHERE (vl.eval_date) IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(vl.eval_date)
                         FROM ces_idw.vendor_load vl
                         WHERE v.vendor_id = vp.vendor_id
                         and v.vendor_name = 'IDC'
                         AND   vp.vendor_pkg_id = vl.vendor_pkg_id
                         AND   TO_CHAR(vl.eval_date,'yyyy-mm') = '2014-06'
                         GROUP BY vl.vendor_pkg_id,
                                  v.vendor_name)                               
AND   vp.vendor_pkg_category_id = vpc.vendor_pkg_category_id
AND   vp.vendor_pkg_id = vl.vendor_pkg_id
AND   vl.load_status_id = vls.load_status_id
ORDER BY vp.vendor_pkg_name
```

when I use `TO_CHAR(vl.eval_date,'yyyy-mm')between '2014-06' and '2014-07'` it shows the result for `'2014-07'`.

Comment: In the other question you mention it is Redshift. Here you tagged 9.1. What is it?

Comment: sorry my friend its my mistake. i need help for this query that's why i added 9.1.

Comment: Cross post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71753/how-to-get-max-date-in-the-table-using-postgresql-v8-0

Comment: The older post is not detailed so uploaded this one

Comment: Reopened since OP removed dupe.

Comment: Are you are sure you are running the [*ancient* version 8.0](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)? If so, upgrade to a current version if at all possible..

Comment: its in cloud. we can't able to upgrade.

Comment: *No* cloud service offers Postgres 8.0. It's so old, the "cloud" hasn't even been invented then.

Comment: tmrw i will upload all the detail. someone review and answer it.

Comment: someone reply to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the Answer for my Question.

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.vendor_name AS vendor,
       vpc.category_name AS V_Type,
       vp.vendor_pkg_name AS Package_name,
       vl.eval_date AS C_Date,
       vls.load_status_name AS Status
FROM ces_idw.vendor v,
     ces_idw.vendor_pkg_category vpc,
     ces_idw.vendor_load vl,
     ces_idw.vendor_pkg vp,
     ces_idw.vendor_load_status vls
WHERE  (vl.eval_date) IN (
                         SELECT DISTINCT MAX(vl.eval_date)
                         FROM  ces_idw.vendor_load vl
                         WHERE v.vendor_id = vp.vendor_id
                         AND   v.vendor_name = 'L&T'
                         AND   vp.vendor_pkg_id = vl.vendor_pkg_id
                         AND  (TO_CHAR(vl.eval_date,'yyyy-mm') between '2013-01' and '2015-12')
                         GROUP BY extract(month from vl.eval_date),vl.vendor_pkg_id, v.vendor_name
                         ) 
AND   vp.vendor_pkg_category_id = vpc.vendor_pkg_category_id
AND   vp.vendor_pkg_id = vl.vendor_pkg_id
AND   vl.load_status_id = vls.load_status_id
ORDER BY vp.vendor_pkg_name
```

Thanks To Everyone

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample data i wrote query this gives you mentioned result set

```
DECLARE @exp table (ID INT,Name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @exp (ID,Name) VALUES (1,'PRICE')
INSERT INTO @exp (ID,Name) VALUES (2,'STOCK')
INSERT INTO @exp (ID,Name) VALUES (3,'INCOME')
INSERT INTO @exp (ID,Name) VALUES (4,'LOAD')
INSERT INTO @exp (ID,Name) VALUES (5,'INITIAL')

DECLARE @exp1 table (ID INT,PID INT,Name VARCHAR(10),Dated Date)
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (1,1,'PRICE','2014-08-05')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (2,1,'PRICE','2014-08-09')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (3,2,'STOCK','2014-08-05')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (4,2,'STOCK','2014-08-05')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (5,3,'INCOME','2014-08-10')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (6,3,'INCOME','2014-08-20')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (7,4,'LOAD','2014-08-10')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (8,4,'LOAD','2014-08-19')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (9,5,'INITIAL','2014-08-05')
INSERT INTO @exp1 (ID,PID,Name,Dated) VALUES (10,5,'INITIAL','2014-08-05')

SELECT DISTINCT groupedtt.ID,groupedtt.PID,tt.Name,groupedtt.MaxDateTime
FROM @exp tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ID,PId, MAX(dated) AS MaxDateTime,DENSE_RANK()OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY ID )RN
    FROM @exp1
    GROUP BY PId,ID) groupedtt 
ON tt.id = groupedtt.PId AND 
RN = 2
```

Comment: one doubt. if i retrieve data from one more table will it retrieve. eg the link between t1 and t2 is by t3.

Comment: yeah we can write another inner join for another table and can get the required output and lot more depends on table structure @benpep

Comment: That's not valid syntax for Postgres

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Your currently accepted solution doesn't seem right.</sup>
My educated guess is that you want:
***Details for the latest row per month for every product of a given vendor.***

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v.vendor_id, vl.vendor_pkg_id
                  , date_trunc('month', vl.eval_date))
       v.vendor_name        AS vendor
     , vpc.category_name    AS v_type
     , vp.vendor_pkg_name   AS package_name
     , vl.eval_date         AS c_date
     , vls.load_status_name AS status
FROM   ces_idw.vendor              v
JOIN   ces_idw.vendor_pkg          vp  USING (vendor_id)
JOIN   ces_idw.vendor_load         vl  USING (vendor_pkg_id)
JOIN   ces_idw.vendor_load_status  vls USING (load_status_id)
JOIN   ces_idw.vendor_pkg_category vpc USING (vendor_pkg_category_id)
WHERE  v.vendor_name = 'L&T'
AND    vl.eval_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
ORDER  BY v.vendor_id, vl.vendor_pkg_id
        , date_trunc('month', vl.eval_date), vl.eval_date DESC;
```

#### Major points

- Returns what I described. Much simpler and faster than your current solution. And probably *correct*.
- Use explicit **`JOIN` syntax**, much clearer. Even simpler with the [**`USING` clause**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM), which your naming convention conveniently allows.
- Use **`DISTINCT ON`**, [available since .. forever](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/queries-select-lists.html) in Postgres.
  [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) instead of `extract()` keeps all months separated. Wouldn't make much sense to group months of multiple years together.
  The added item `vl.eval_date DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause picks the latest row per month.
  Detailed explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:
  [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- Since it is unclear whether `vendor_name` is unique, I included `vendor_id` in the `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` clauses accordingly.
- Do not transform your **`date`** column to `text` in the `WHERE` clause, this is expensive nonsense and makes it impossible to use simple indexes. The resulting expression is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).
- Do not use the multiply twisted and expensive subquery, connected `IN`. Completely replaced by `DISTINCT ON`.
  In particular, combining `DISTINCT` with `MAX(vl.eval_date)` doesn't make sense.
- To make this *fast* you only need **indexes** on `(Vendor_load.eval_date)` and `(vendor.vendor_name)` -  in addition to the obvious primary keys and indexes on foreign key columns.

All links to the manual for Postgres 8.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer But DISTINCT ON is not working in my PostgreSQL. That's Why i Wrote the code which i post. @Erwin Brandstetter

Comment: @benpep: I suggest you finally declare what you are working with - like you should have done to begin with. Is it Redshift? What do you get from `SELECT version()`. Edit the question with this basic information.

Comment: yes. its my mistake. it shows.                                PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2  (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.797